# Dynamodb UnmarshalListOfMaps returns InvalidUnmarshalError emptyOrigError

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Performing a simple dynamodb query and trying to marshal the results into a result list produces the error.

```
    queryItemOutput, err := cdb.db.Query(queryInput)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var returnedItems []pb.Item
    err = dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalListOfMaps(queryItemOutput.Items, returnedItems)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
```

`Expected :*dynamodbattribute.InvalidUnmarshalError(&dynamodbattribute.InvalidUnmarshalError{emptyOrigError:dynamodbattribute.emptyOrigError{}, Type:(*reflect.rtype)(0xbe95a0)})`

Answer (score 0):

The key is to pass a pointer to the list you wish dynamodb to marshal in to. Seems extremely simple but the error was rather cryptic and it took me longer than I care to admit to figure out the issue.

```
    err = dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalListOfMaps(queryItemOutput.Items, &returnedItems)
```